# Unable to access removable storage in Android

Tags: android, android-storage

**Problem** :
Write to the SD card of the device.

**What am doing** :

```
context.getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

This returns 2 file objects.

First one points to :

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/filecopier/files/Download/

Second one points to :

> /storage/7AC1-0CFE/Android/data/filecopier/files/Download/

**Issue** : The second one writes to SD card. But it is the private location not accessible outside the app. I want to write to a location which is accessible to other apps as well (like Download folder)

**Expected** : /storage/7AC1-0CFE/Download/

How do I access this location?

Comment: "How do I access this location?" -- you don't. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html for more. Use the Storage Access Framework and allow the user to control where on the user's device you put the user's content.

Comment: Use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose the right folder.

Comment: Thanks for the info @CommonsWare! Really well written detailed blog on this. Helped me understand better.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps! Looking into this.